# Transformation of a given pandas dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this below. This gives me the distances in degrees from individual points to the following cities,viz, Fargo,Orange and Jersey City. But each column in the below dataframe like 'Fargo' has its row numbers 0 through 3 populated by the shortest 4 distances to any of the points and for the rest of the 8 rows it is getting populated because we are finding out the 4 shortest distances to another city 'Orange' and so on. To summarise from the below dataframe

```
Points = ['Point1','Point4','Point5','Point2','Point2','Point5','Point1','Point4','Point3','Point6','Point4','Point1']
Fargo = [2.90300755828,3.91961324034,21.9825588597,24.3141420303,24.3141420303,21.9825588597,2.90300755828,3.91961324034,25.3599772676,25.8509998739,3.91961324034,2.90300755828]
Orange = [25.5464458592,27.1527975618,6.17298387907,4.80214941294,4.80214941294,6.17298387907,25.5464458592,27.1527975618,46.4066249652,45.8853687976,27.1527975618,25.5464458592]
Jersey_City = [21.1030418227,19.6763385681,39.3194029761,41.8121131045,41.8121131045,39.3194029761,21.1030418227,19.6763385681,2.09632277264,2.67885042284,19.6763385681,21.1030418227]
toy_data=pd.DataFrame(index=Points,columns=['Fargo','Orange','Jersey_City'])
toy_data['Fargo']= Fargo
toy_data['Orange']=Orange
toy_data['Jersey_City']=Jersey_City
```

Lets say for the column `Fargo` the first 4 rows : rows 0 through 3 represent the points which have the shortest distances from `Fargo`. Similarly in the column `Orange` rows 4 through 7 represent the points which have the shortest distances to `Orange` and now in rows 4 through 7 the column `Fargo` gets populated with the distances from the nearest four points to `Orange`. But I want a frame where I get the 4 points having the shortest distances to each City in one single dataframe. So what you see here in the column `Fargo` rows 0-3 are its 4 nearest points,in column `Orange`, rows 4-7 are its nearest 4 points, in column `Jersey City` the rows 8-11 are its 4 nearest points. I want to keep those 4 nearest points for each city and remove the remaining as I have done below.
What I want is this:

```
Fargo = [2.9030075582789885,3.919613240342197,21.982558859743925,24.314142030334484,'NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN']
Orange = ['NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN',4.802149412942695,6.172983879065276,25.546445859236265,27.15279756182145,'NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN']
Jersey_City = ['NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN','NAN',2.096322772642856,2.67885042283533,19.676338568056806,21.10304182269932]
result_wanted_data =pd.DataFrame(index= Points,columns = ['Fargo','Orange','Jersey_City'])
result_wanted_data['Fargo']=Fargo
result_wanted_data['Orange']=Orange
result_wanted_data['Jersey_City']=Jersey_City
```

Comment: Please can you better explain the problem and what you are trying to obtain.

Comment: name 'data' is not defined! Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlexandreNixon I hope you understand the problem now.

Comment: @user32185 I think the 'data' you were asking is given now. Apologies for the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is not exactly that what I guess you wanted but I think this will solve the purpose:

```
newdf=np.empty([12])

for i in range(12):
    newdf[i]=data.iloc[i,[(math.ceil((i+1)/4))]]
newdf1=[]
cities=list(data.columns.values[1:])
for i in range(12):
     newdf1.append(cities[(math.ceil((i+1)/4)-1)])
strs = ["" for x in range(12)]  
for i in range(12):

    strs[i]=data.iloc[i,0]

final_data=pd.DataFrame(columns=['city','point','distance' ])
final_data['city']=newdf1
final_data['distance']=newdf
final_data['point']=strs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.split()` and a for loop:

```
x = 0
split = []
for num in range(len(toy_data.columns)-1):
    split.append(x+4)
    x+=4

dfs = np.split(toy_data, split)

data = []
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    data.append(pd.DataFrame(dfs[i][dfs[i].columns[i]]))
pd.concat(data, sort=False)

          Fargo   Orange    Jersey_City
Point1  2.903008    NaN         NaN
Point4  3.919613    NaN         NaN
Point5  21.982559   NaN         NaN
Point2  24.314142   NaN         NaN
Point2     NaN     4.802149     NaN
Point5     NaN     6.172984     NaN
Point1     NaN     25.546446    NaN
Point4     NaN     27.152798    NaN
Point3     NaN       NaN      2.096323
Point6     NaN       NaN      2.678850
Point4     NaN       NaN      19.676339
Point1     NaN       NaN      21.103042
```

Comment: TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'. It shows this error..

Comment: pd.__version__
Out[924]: '0.21.1'

Comment: @Saradamani Sort was added in 0.23 I believe. you should just be able to remove that param

Comment: Beautiful answer Yes I saw this works. My solution was ofcourse different..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
intervals = np.array_split(np.arange(toy_data.shape[0]), 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Distances'], index=toy_data.reset_index().index)
for i, j in zip(range(toy_data.shape[1]), intervals):
    df.loc[j,'Distances'] = toy_data.reset_index(drop=True).iloc[j,i]

print(df)

    Distances
0    2.90301
1    3.91961
2    21.9826
3    24.3141
4    4.80215
5    6.17298
6    25.5464
7    27.1528
8    2.09632
9    2.67885
10   19.6763
11    21.103
```